# why op tf.tile() is always running on CPU even if I have set to run on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, cpu

this is the timeline from my training task, and it shows that op tf.tile() is running on cpu, and costs 1/3 of total time. I want to optimize it to accelerate the training speed.
[timeline from tracing log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRFHU.png)

```html
with tf.name_scope("key_masking"):
            key_masks = tf.sequence_mask(keys_length, tf.shape(keys)[1])   # (N, T_k)
            key_masks = tf.tile(key_masks, [num_heads, 1])  # (h*N, T_k)
            key_masks = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(key_masks, 1), 
                [1, tf.shape(queries)[1], 1])  # (h*N, T_q, T_k)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using TensorFlow version 1.4, or earlier. [A bool GPU kernel was only added in version 1.5](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/c86793dd597649fdf64964f87e6f8e896966e490).

Comment: yes, it's the cause of the problem, and I try to  use tf.cast(key_masks, tf.int16) before tf.tile, then use tf.cast(key_masks, tf.bool) after tf.tile on tensorflow_1.4. I think the best way is to use version 1.5+.